# Firebase: Saving data just before signout

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

In my iOS app, I want to try saving a piece of user data just before the user signs out.

-- updated code with same problem. "USER HAS BEEN LOGGED OUT" prints before "FELL INTO COMPLETION BLOCK".

```
let tryToLogout = {
    try! FIRAuth.auth()!.signOut()
    print("USER HAS BEEN LOGGED OUT")
}

rootRef.child(path).setValue(value, withCompletionBlock: { (_,_) in
    print("FELL INTO COMPLETION BLOCK")
    tryToLogout()
})
```

Unfortunately, I sometimes get a permission denied on that setValue attempt. I presume that what's going on here is the user is getting de-authed by signing out before the setValue can take hold. That would make complete sense to me if it were not for the fact that the signOut() call is clearly inside of the setValue's completion block.

Any explanation?

UPDATED ------------------------------------------------------------------------
I've kind of figured out the issue here. The rootRef.child.setValue stuff is inside of a general set value function that I made for ease of use throughout my project. When I take the contents of that function (the setValue code you see above) and run it on its own (not inside of a separate function call), the problem goes away and the print statements are in the correct order. I believe this means that my problem was caused by the call stack. Signing out the user was the last thing on the call stack, and so it was therefore the first thing off the call stack - the first thing to get executed.

The code below should demonstrate this issue

```
func setFireBaseValue(path: String, value: NSObject, completionCode: () ) {
    getRootRef().child(path).setValue(value, withCompletionBlock: { (_,_) in
        print("FELL INTO A COMPLETION BLOCK")
        completionCode
    })
}

let tryToLogout = {
    try! FIRAuth.auth()!.signOut()
    print("USER HAS BEEN LOGGED OUT")
}

setFireBaseValue(path: "test", value: "hi" as NSString, completionCode: tryToLogout())
```

Comment: The completion block will only be called once the `setValue()` has been executed on the server and the client has received acknowledgement. I see no way that could trigger a permission denied. You might be able to see exactly what's going on if you [enable debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/interface_f_i_r_database.html#add018db6d76362436734f66daa471256).

Comment: I added a print("FELL INTO COMPLETION BLOCK") as the first line inside of the completion block. Then I removed the signOut() and encapsulated it inside of a closure containing a print("USER IS SIGNED OUT"). Then I called the closure inside of the completion block. When all this gets executed, the "USER IS SIGNED OUT" prints before the "FELL INTO COMPLETION BLOCK" without exception. It must be that the signOut() method is getting called before the completion block, yes?

Comment: That proves that `tryToLogout` is called before the completion block is called. It must be invoked from somewhere else. Any way to look at the callstack of when `tryToLogout` is called, to see where it's coming from?

Comment: Please see my update. I'm quite glad I just learned about the call stack in my college class :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use OnCompleteListener to listen for the successful addition of data to firebase database and sign out after successful data updation. If there was any error in saving the data notify the user about it and proceed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:-

```
rootRef.child(path).setValue(value, withCompletionBlock: { (err,ref) in

 if err == nil && ref == nil{
   try! FIRAuth.auth()!.signOut()
    }
 })
```